# How to genrate column values using row index values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i have pandas DataFrame:

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

idx = list(product([1,2,3],repeat=2))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(idx, names=["x","y"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=["data1"], data=[randint(1,100) for _ in range(9)])
```

| x | y | data1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 34 |
|  | 2 | 45 |
|  | 3 | 23 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
|  | 2 | 8 |
|  | 3 | 41 |
| 3 | 1 | 58 |
|  | 2 | 43 |
|  | 3 | 9 |

How can generate a new column based on index values and `data1` values?

something like:

```
def calculate(v):
  return v.index["x"] +v.index["y"]) * v.data1

df.apply(calculate,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) the operation to create a `new_col` :

```
out = df.eval("new_col=(x+y)*data1")
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

     data1  new_col
x y                
1 1     34       68
  2     45      135
  3     23       92
2 1      7       21
  2      8       32
  3     41      205
3 1     58      232
  2     43      215
  3      9       54
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

I think it is not good to use a random sample for a short example when asking a question.

So I created a new code for your example.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], names=["x","y"])
data = [34, 45, 23, 7, 8, 41, 58, 43, 9]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['data1'])
```

**Code**

First, convert the index to a DataFrame and then sum it by axis=1.

Then, multiply it by df['data1'].

```
df['data1'].mul(df.index.to_frame().sum(axis=1))
```

output:

```
x  y
1  1     68
   2    135
   3     92
2  1     21
   2     32
   3    205
3  1    232
   2    215
   3     54
dtype: int64
```